# installing business network in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

i have problem with installing business network and i have encountered this error:

✖ Installing business network. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying install business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed
Command failed

would you please help me?